# Mulit-Day All-Day Event

Tags: icalendar, vcalendar, rfc5545, vcal

I am having issues getting the right syntax for an all day event which spans multiple days. Here is my ICAL event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//http://XXX//Event
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID="America/Chicago";VALUE=DATE:20150809
DTEND;TZID="America/Chicago";VALUE=DATE:20150812
SUMMARY:Event Name
DESCRIPTION:Event Description
LOCATION:Event Location
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Shows up great in Mac Calendar:
[image]

But in Outlook, it starts at 1AM and isn't marked as all day:
[image]

Comment: I can also confirm that this works properly in Google Calendar and...Lotus Notes. What's does it look like if you create what you want in Outlook and export that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I just tested, it seems that Outlook does not allow all-day ICAL events to have a timezone specified. Seems stupid, but changing the file to this made it work:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//http://XXX//Event
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150809
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150812
SUMMARY:Event Name
DESCRIPTION:Event Description
LOCATION:Event Location
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: It's not that stupid. TZID is simply not allowed for all-day events. It's possible that outlook uses the existence of TZID to figure out if it should be treated as 'all-day' or not. The definition of an "all-day event" is an event that lasts all day regardless of timezone, a so-called "floating date" so it makes sense.