# ical multi-full-day is missing one day

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

If I have a multi fullDay event in my generated ical, it is missing the last day. Screenshot of the calendar below.

This ical event **MultiFullday** should be from 21/05 - 24/05 (21 and 24 included), but 24/05 is excluded

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170521
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170524
UID:590b6335922a5
DTSTAMP:20170504T192157Z
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:
URL;VALUE=URI:
SUMMARY:MultiFullday
END:VEVENT
```

This ical event **Test Fullday** should be only on 25/05 and it is.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170525
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170525
UID:590b63359237b
DTSTAMP:20170504T192157Z
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:
URL;VALUE=URI:
SUMMARY:Test Fullday
END:VEVENT
```

The events are wrapped into this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Vereinsplaner//Vereinsplaner v1.0//DE
URL:https://www.vereinsplaner.at/ical/user/58b7118b6d716e7478abb2.ics
NAME:Vereinsplaner 
X-WR-CALNAME:Vereinsplaner 
DESCRIPTION: Termine von Vereinsplaner.at
X-WR-CALDESC:Termine von Vereinsplaner.at 
X-WR-RELCALID:VereinsplanerCal
COLOR:11:174:219
X-WR-TIMEZONE:UTC 
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H 
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
... // Between here
END:VCALENDAR
```

When i import the ical, this is the result. As you can see the multi fullDay event is missing the last day

[image]

According to this [Mulit-Day All-Day Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620641/mulit-day-all-day-event) , my `DTSTART` and `DTEND` are in the right format.

Comment: Meanwhile i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407052/fullcalendar-end-date-wrong-by-one-day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime i solved this problem by adding a day to the enddate.

According to this [Fullcalendar end date wrong by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407052/fullcalendar-end-date-wrong-by-one-day) the enddate is not included.

instead of

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170521
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170524
```

I write

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170521
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170525
```

I am open for any other solution. But maybe this answer will help anybody else.

Comment: According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545, the DTEND is "non-inclusive". So this is the correct solution